# No idea what this pointer could be pointing to and unable to interpret the result

Tags: c++, c, pointers, hex

This was given as a past question in an exam but i'm unable to understand the result that is obtained of the last 4 printf functions. I get the conversion to hexadecimal for the first 2 but i don't really see how there are characters at

```
ptr[0] to ptr[3]
```

This is the section of code that was compiled and run.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    typedef unsigned char byte;

    unsigned int nines = 999;
    byte * ptr = (byte *) &nines;

    printf ("%x\n",nines);
    printf ("%x\n",nines * 0x10);
    printf ("%d\n",ptr[0]);
    printf ("%d\n",ptr[1]);
    printf ("%d\n",ptr[2]);
    printf ("%d\n",ptr[3]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and this was the corresponding output

```
3e7
3e70
231
3
0
0
```

Comment: Hint: write down the binary representation of `999`, taking into account that an `unsigned int` variable most likely takes 4 bytes.

Comment: Change those `%d` to `%x` and run it again. It should be considerably clearer.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall the most important part is `most likely` and it depends on architecture, then this question can't be answer correctly

Comment: 999 = 231 * 2^0 + 3 * 2^8 + 0 * 2^16 + 0 * 2^24

Comment: this posted code does not compile.  Analysis indicates it is missing two statements: `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` The compiler also outputs warnings about unused variables `argc` and `argv[]`  When not using those parameters, use the signature `int main( void )`.  When asking a runtime question (as this question is) please post 1) code that cleanly compiles, 2) the actual inputs, if any 3) the actual outputs and 4) the expected outputs.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `byte * ptr = (byte *) &nines;` you set the address of `ptr` to be the same address of `nines`. This has a value of `999` and in hex is `0x3e7`

From the problem, I am assuming that an `int` has 4 bytes and this is a little endian system. i.e. bytes are stored like this.

```
---------------------------------
| 0xe7  |  0x03 |  0x00 |  0x00 |
---------------------------------
  ptr     ptr+1   ptr+2    ptr+3
```

So when you print them out, you get the values of `231`, `3`, `0` and `0`  (231 is equal to 0xe7)

In the little endian system, followed by intel processors and most microcontrollers today, the least significant byte is stored first and the most significant byte is stored last.

On the other hand, we have the big endian system, followed by some older Motorola controllers and power PC's. In this the most significant byte is stored first. The output in those systems would be 0, 0, 3 and 231.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an exam like this, I suggest you to change lecturer as soon as possible.

The representation of `unsigned int` is implementation specified, it depends on your machine for its size, endianness.

Anyway, casting from a `unsigned int*` to `char*`then read it value directly should be an undefined behavior.

In little endian like x86 machine, your `unsigned int` of `999` is represented as:

```
| 0xE7 | 0x03 | 0x00 | 0x00 |
-----------------------------
  ptr    ptr+1  ptr+2  ptr+3
```

with number between `|` is the value in that `byte`. Hence, it will be printed as:

```
231 3 0 0
```

On another machine, let's say a 32 bit, Big Endian (e.g Atmel AVR32), it will be represented as:

```
| 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x03 | 0xE7 |
-----------------------------
  ptr    ptr+1  ptr+2  ptr+3
```

then it will print:

```
0 0 3 231
```

In another machine, let's say a 32 bit, middle endian, it will be represented as:

```
| 0x03 | 0xE7 | 0x00 | 0xE0 |
-----------------------------
  ptr    ptr+1  ptr+2  ptr+3
```

then it will print:

```
3 231 0 0
```

In the older machine, let's say a 16 bit little endian machine, it is represented as:

```
| 0xE7 | 0x03 | xx| xx |
------------------------
  ptr    ptr+1  ptr+2  ptr+3
```

with `xx` is unspecified value, there is another undefined behavior.

In a 64 bit big endian machine, it is represented as:

```
| 0x00| 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x03 | 0xE7
-----------------------------
  ptr    ptr+1  ptr+2  ptr+3
```

it will print:

```
0 0 0 0
```

That's said, there's no exact answer for exam's question. And if yes, it still invokes undefined behavior.

Further reading about [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Answer (score 1):

**This code is platform-dependent.**

Given that your platform is:

- Little Endian
- `CHAR_BIT == 8`
- `sizeof(int) == 4`

The binary representation of 999 in memory is `11100111 00000011 00000000 00000000`.

Hence the decimal representation of 999 in memory is `231 3 0 0`.

---

As a side-note, you should bring it to the attention of your instructor at school/college/university, that since this code is platform-dependent, it is a very bad example to be given as part of an exam.

Answer (score 0):

This code displays the values of each individual byte of the (assumed to be 32-bit) number `nines`.

`nines`'s value is 999 in decimal, 3E7 in hexadecimal, and according to the values printed, it's stored in little-endian byte order (the "least significant" byte comes first).

It's easier to see if you convert the values to hexadecimal as well:

```
printf ("%x\n",ptr[0]);
printf ("%x\n",ptr[1]);
printf ("%x\n",ptr[2]);
printf ("%x\n",ptr[3]);
```

Which will display this:

```
E7
3
0
0
```

Also, you could interpret the decimal values this way:

```
231 + 3*256 + 0*65536 + 0*16777216 = 999
```

Answer (score 0):

`nines` is an unsigned 32bit integer on the stack (note that it is possible for `int` to be 64bit wide, but it does not seem to be the case here).
`ptr` is a pointer, which gets initialized to the address of `nines`. Since it is a pointer, you can use array syntax to access the value at the address pointed to. We assume it is a little endian machine, so `ptr[0]` is the first (least significant) byte of `nines`, `ptr[1]` is the next, etc.
`231` is then the value of the least significant byte, in hex it is `0xe7`